# React native, pass index.ios.js path to package manager

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm writing a small POC for my learning benefit. MI want to prove that I can share business logic to a web app and it's react native counterpart. The repo mis below.

https://github.com/danfernand/rate-topic

Essentially under src folder I have a web and native folders. In that folder I have all my actions/reducers/utils.

I installed react-native as a dependency and am using the following run command.

```
export BABEL_ENV=native && npm run clean && ./node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh --project-path './src/native/' --reset-cache
```

I have tried all that I can find online but can't seem to be able to set the folder where the index.ios.js is. I get an error by the package manager.

Cannot find entry file index.ios.js in any of the roots: ['']

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Find this in another stackoverflow question.

Apparently you just need to use --root

Credit where its due

[React cannot find entry file in any of the roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388704/react-cannot-find-entry-file-in-any-of-the-roots)