# Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots:[ Android ]

Tags: react-native

I am trying to start my hello world app using react native using windows 7 and an android device. There is a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29388704/react-cannot-find-entry-file-in-any-of-the-roots) but I have failed make it work.

Commands I have run so far to set up and lead to this issue.

1. Created the app: `react-native init helloMe`
2. Moved to the root Dir[helloMe]. `react-native run-android`
3. Android Device is set up okay and showing in CMD using adb
4. Opened another CMD window then ran: `react-native start`
5. Ran `react-native run-android` again.
6. Red Screen is shown on phone with this error unable to [load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows)
7. Trying to fix it with the solution in step 6 leads to another error which is why I am here. below is my CMD log.

   ```
   E:\testdir\react_ws\helloMe>react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.android.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
   Scanning 558 folders for symlinks in E:\testdir\react_ws\helloMe\node_modules (30ms)
   Scanning 558 folders for symlinks in E:\testdir\react_ws\helloMe\node_modules (20ms)
   Loading dependency graph, done.
   Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots: ["E:\\testdir\\react_ws\\helloMe"]
   E:\testdir\react_ws\helloMe>
   ```

Now I am getting another error when I try to fix the problem with the above solution.

```
Cannot find entry file index.android.js in any of the roots: ["E:\\testdir
\\react_ws\\helloMe"]
```

If have tried to apply this fix from [here](http://npm%20run%20start%20--%20--root%20%3Cdirectory_with_your_react_component_js_sources%3E)

```
npm run start -- --root <directory_with_your_react_component_js_sources>
```

I since I am running the command in the project root, I ran this instead 
`npm run start -- --root ./` but it did not work.

This is my root project structure

```
__tests__  app.json          index.ios.js  node_modules  yarn.lock
android    index.android.js  ios           package.json
```

I hope I am clear, any help would be highly appreciated. Device is stuck on red screen with a 404.

React-native-version

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.46.0
```

Thanks. [image: Requested Project root Structure Snapshot]

[image: CMD][image: NPM Start][image: Sceenshot 2]

Comment: share your react native project skeleton

Comment: Hi, Do you want a screenshot? cos I have not changed anything from the basic app

Comment: _tests__  app.json          index.ios.js  node_modules  yarn.lock
android    index.android.js  ios           package.jso

Comment: Yes i need screenshot

Comment: I have added the Image

Comment: in cmd , move to your root folder and the run "react-native run-android"

Comment: And share the screen dump of result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148490/discussion-between-isaac-chambers-and-arunkumar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed the version of react project to a lower one from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34211131/new-react-native-project-with-old-version-of-react-native)

```
npm install -g rninit

rninit init [Project Name] --source react-native@0.40.0
```

Worked okay for both on both iOS and Android on . If you get **Error Could not get BatchedBridge**. run this

```
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**1: In cmd With This Command `ipconfig` Find Your ip**
And put that in `Dev Sttings` => `Debug server host& port for device`

**2: turn on your Device wifi**

[image: a]

And

[image: b]